# python argument using < (io redirection) in linux

Tags: python, shell, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

In python 3 how to read an entire file using {<} from Linux command prompt. How to access and figure out the input is {textfile.txt} or {extract.txt} inside python code.

example

{python script.py < textfile.txt > result.log} or {python script.py < ../directory2/extract.txt > ~/test/result.log}

Comment: You can't tell the name of the file. The shell doesn't give you that information.

Comment: Once you use that redirection, your python script is no longer reading from a file, it's reading from standard input (file descriptor 0)

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

input_text = sys.stdin.read()
```

`sys.stdin` is like a file, so you can also use `.readlines()` or iterate over it line by line.